# How to use Spring Cloud Config with local GIT repo instead of GitHub?

Tags: spring-cloud

Has anyone configured Spring Cloud Config to use a local GIT repo instead of GitHub? If so could you share your config?

Answer (score 11):

The Spring Cloud Config server [tests](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/JGitEnvironmentRepositoryTests.java) do this.

The uri ends up looking like this `file:./target/test-classes/config-repo/`

You can do something like this in bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:/path/to/your/git/repo
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid using git repos entirely, and get all the configuration info from a local properties file?

Comment: Three follow on questions: 1) should the file: path end with a "/" (it doesn't in your .properties file), and 2) should the repo path be to the .git directory in the local file system, or to its parent; that is, file:/Users/foo/example/.git or /Users/foo/example/ and 3) I think that in some cases Spring only uses bootstrap.properties, and does not use bootstrap.yml -- is this one of these cases?

Comment: I don't think a slash matters.  It shouldn't point to a .git directory.  It shouldn't matter bootstrap.properties or .yml

Comment: I just tested the filepath clarification that Steve Byrne asked about.  Confirming that both `file:/path/to/your/git/repo` and `file:/path/to/your/git/repo/` work but not file:/path/to/your/git/repo/.git.

Answer (score 1):

As of spring-cloud-config-montior 2.0.0.RELEASE, FileMonitorConfiguration discards monitoring changes on local git repository paths unless they are resolved as FileSystemResource. Unfortunately, ApplicationContext DefaultResourceResolver returns FileUrlResource instead of FileSystemResource if local git repo path is given like file:/path/to/your/git/repo/.
My workaround is to create a custom ProtocolResolver, which is SPI for extending DefaultResourceLoader, and utilize FileSystemResourceLoader to return FileSystemResource if local git repo path starts with '//'.

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ConfigserviceApplication.class);
        app.addInitializers(new ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>() {

            @Override
            public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
                ProtocolResolver resolver = new ProtocolResolver() {

                    private FileSystemResourceLoader resourceLoader = new FileSystemResourceLoader();

                    @Override
                    public Resource resolve(String location, ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
                        if(location != null && location.startsWith("//")) {
                            return this.resourceLoader.getResource(location);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                applicationContext.addProtocolResolver(resolver);
            }
        });
        app.run(args);
```